# Initialization and modification of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, initialization

Due to my few concepts of Java, I have a basic question.

In this situation:

```
Device devA = new Device();
Device devB = new Device();
ArrayList<Device> allDev = new ArrayList();
allDev.add(devA);
allDev.add(devB);
```

If after that I modify `devA` or `devB`, also `allDev` will be modified accordingly?

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic or anything but why not try it out in code?  Things like this are better learned that way.  If you are still having trouble that way then come back here, post your code and the trouble you are having.  You need to help yourself before others can try to help you.

Comment: @Pete, I understand your opinion and next time I will try before ask :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You add a reference to `devA` and `devB` to the `ArrayList`. Any change to these object will be reflected to them when you access them through the `ArrayList` as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Java when you create a new Object you are getting a reference/handle to the object and anytime you have a handle to the object and making changes to the object, anyone having the same reference will be able to see those changes.

So the answer to your question is yes because you are in essence making changes to the same object.